# Can't login with HuggingFace oauth

Tags: php, oauth-2.0, huggingface

I am trying to build an authentication solution via HuggingFace.co as per the docs: https://huggingface.co/docs/hub/oauth. I have done following but not sure what mistake I am doing. Please help me out to print email and profile details. TIA!

Note: I have set the URL (http://localhost/ai/) and callback (http://localhost/ai/hf) in my developer application:

I have following code:

1. huggingface.php (http://localhost/ai/huggingface.php)

```
$clientId = '37779938-b...';
$clientSecret = '098260e6-1...';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/ai/hf';

// Step 1: Redirect user to Hugging Face's authorization page with desired scopes
$authorizationUrl = 'https://huggingface.co/oauth/authorize';
$authorizationUrl .= '?client_id=' . $clientId;
$authorizationUrl .= '&redirect_uri=' . $redirectUri;
$authorizationUrl .= '&response_type=code';
$authorizationUrl .= '&scope=openid%20profile%20email'; // Adjust the scope as needed
$authorizationUrl .= '&state=' . bin2hex(random_bytes(16));

header('Location: ' . $authorizationUrl);
exit;

// The user will be redirected back to your specified redirect URI with an authorization code.
?>
```

and hf.php

```
<?php
$clientId = '37779938-b...';
$clientSecret = '098260e6-1...';
$redirectUri = 'http://localhost/ai/hf';

// Step 2: Handle the callback and verify the state parameter
if (isset($_GET['code']) && isset($_GET['state'])) {
    $state = $_GET['state'];
    $code = $_GET['code'];

    // Verify the state parameter to prevent CSRF attacks
    // Perform your state validation here

    // Step 3: Use the code to get an access token and id token
    $tokenUrl = 'https://huggingface.co/oauth/token';
    $tokenData = [
        'client_id' => $clientId,
        'client_secret' => $clientSecret,
        'redirect_uri' => $redirectUri,
        'code' => $_GET['code'],
        'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
    ];

    $options = [
        'http' => [
            'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
            'method' => 'POST',
            'content' => http_build_query($tokenData),
        ],
    ];

    $context = stream_context_create($options);
    $response = @file_get_contents($tokenUrl, false, $context);

    if ($response === false) {
        die("Failed to make the token request. Check your server configuration.");
    }

    $tokens = json_decode($response, true);

    if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
        die("Failed to decode token JSON. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
    }

    if ($tokens !== null) {
        // Step 4: Use the access token to fetch user data
        $userInfoUrl = 'https://huggingface.co/oauth/userinfo';
        $userInfoOptions = [
            'http' => [
                'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $tokens['access_token'] . "\r\n",
                'method' => 'GET',
            ],
        ];

        $userInfoContext = stream_context_create($userInfoOptions);
        $userInfoResponse = @file_get_contents($userInfoUrl, false, $userInfoContext);

        if ($userInfoResponse === false) {
            die("Failed to make the user data request.");
        }

        // Process the user profile data
        $userData = json_decode($userInfoResponse, true);

        if (json_last_error() !== JSON_ERROR_NONE) {
            die("Failed to decode user data JSON. Error: " . json_last_error_msg());
        }

        echo '<pre>';
        print_r($userData);
        echo '</pre>';
    } else {
        die("Failed to decode token JSON.");
    }
} else {
    echo "Authorization code or state is missing.";
}
?>
```

**I'm getting following error in hf.php**

> Failed to make the token request. Check your server configuration.

Comment: The `header` value in your context options should not end with `\r\n`.

Comment: Removed still getting same error.

Comment: Add `'ignore_errors' => true` to your stream context options, so that you get access to the actual response body.

Comment: By adding I got error: ( ! ) Warning: Undefined array key "access_token" in D:\wmp\www\ai\hf.php on line 51
LINE 51 : `'header' => "Authorization: Bearer " . $tokens['access_token'] . "\r\n",`

Comment: You got an HTTP error response from the API, so likely the response is _not_ JSON in this case. So check what it contains, _before_ you try to decode it as JSON.

Comment: `{"error":"invalid_client","error_description":"\"client_assertion_type\" is required"}`
Before converting to JSON I got this in response.

Comment: Thanks! I got the the response using JWT. :D Thanks again it's working now :D

Answer (score -1):

The error "Failed to make the token request. Check your server configuration." suggests that there is an issue with making the HTTP request to the Hugging Face token endpoint. Here are a few things you can check and modify in your code:

1. **Enable Error Reporting:**
   Add the following lines at the beginning of your PHP scripts to enable error reporting. This will help you see if there are any PHP errors.

   ```php
   error_reporting(E_ALL);
   ini_set('display_errors', 1);
   ```
2. **Verify HTTP Context Options:**
   Ensure that the HTTP context options are correctly set. Modify your code as follows:

   ```php
   $options = [
       'http' => [
           'header' => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
           'method' => 'POST',
           'content' => http_build_query($tokenData),
           'ignore_errors' => true, // Ignore HTTP errors to check the response content
       ],
   ];

   $context = stream_context_create($options);
   $response = file_get_contents($tokenUrl, false, $context);

   if ($response === false) {
       $error = error_get_last();
       die("Failed to make the token request. Error: " . $error['message']);
   }
   ```

   The addition of `'ignore_errors' => true` allows you to inspect the response content even if the request results in an HTTP error.
3. **Check for HTTPS Connection:**
   Ensure that your server supports HTTPS. Some OAuth providers require a secure connection for token requests. If your server is running over HTTP, consider using HTTPS.

Comment: Instead of posting generated answers, you should read the comments and see that the problem has already been solved.